# How to ignore .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

Is there a way to tell Apache to ignore other .htaccess files under current directory?
For example:

```
/web/.htaccess [this is parsed, I would like to define the rule here]
/web/uploads/.htaccess [this should be ignored]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your main apache config, add the directive `AllowOverride None`.

This will prevent it from looking at .htaccess files.

For more info, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: No, I need .htaccess in web dir, but don't want apache to look any further, e.g. web/uploads. Do I make myself clear?

Comment: You'll have to apply it to  a new directory/location `<Location /uploads> AllowOverride None </Location>`

Comment: can this be defined in .htaccess file?

Comment: No, it has to be in the main config. Also, I was incorrect in saying it can be in the `<Location>` directive, it must be in the `<Directory>`